# Maximum volume of an open box with a square base?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

A box with a square base and an open top is to be made. You have $1200\operatorname{cm}^2$ of material to make it. What is the maximum volume the box could have?

Here's what I did:

$$1200 = x^2+4xz;$$ where $x$ is length of base and $z$ is height of box.

Also, let the volume of box be $V$, then

$$V= x^2 z =x^2\left(\frac{1200-x^2}{4x}\right)=300x - (0.25)x^3$$

$$V ' = 300-\frac{3}{4}x^2$$

$$300=\frac{3}{4}x^2$$

$$x=20$$

so the max volume should be $300(20)-.25(20)^3 = 4000(\operatorname{cm}^3)$

I feel like this is incorrect but this is what I have tried. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure if my logic is correct. It seems to be because what I've done is I found the x value that corresponds to the maximum volume of the box and then I plugged that x value into the function that gives the volume so it makes sense to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: And because this was worth 12 points on my exam yesterday and it seems too easy.

Comment: If you found $x$ for the maximum volume and you have the volume in terms of $x$ then you found the maximum volume. Your logic is correct.

Comment: If you look over the work above and confirm this I will think about sparing you as supreme squirrel leader.

Comment: I checked it and it's correct. That's why I was curious of why you thought it was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you great sir. You have been spared.